# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once

Tags: angularjs

В браузере выскакивает ошибка вот такого типа: 
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
И не отображает информацию. Что не так?

```js
angular
.module('app', ['ui.router','templates'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state ('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'main/_home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home'); 
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/Phone_Red.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.11/ngStorage.min.js"></script>

 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<ui-view ></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это значит, что главный скрипт для ангуляра загружается два раза. Например где-ьл еще грузится `angular.min.js`.